# Why is Keyboard C selecting the Cursor and not Circle Select?

Tags: edit-mode, selection-tools

When I press `C` on the Keyboard in Edit Mode in 2.8, it activates the Cursor tool, instead of Circle Select.

I tried to verify the shortcut in Preferences by searching for Circle Select, but became more confused, because while `mask.select_circle` is bound to Keyboard `C`, there are multiple entries, and some such as `view3d.select_circle` have the `Ctrl` modifier set to `Subtract` mode and `Shift` set to `Extend`: however the behaviour I observe is that `Shift` Subtracts and `Ctrl` does nothing.

How should I interpret these keymaps? And what is the correct way to set a shortcut for Circle Select in Edit mode?

Comment: maybe in the Preferences > Keymap, use the Key-Binding search field?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to fix this but u have a cover up , you can get into circle select by clicking on the small triangle in the select box tool and then select the circle select